# DotNetOpenAuth redirection URL results to page not found

Tags: authentication, mobile, browser, dotnetopenauth

I have deployed a service using DotNetOpenAuth library.

The service authenticates against 4 providers (Google, Yahoo, Windows and Facebook)

I am having a problem with Windows and Facebook (Oauth protocol)

My services works fine when accessed through any browser. It redirects to the correct provider after selection, authenticates and replies back with the email address.

But the service does not work when accessed through a Mobile device. Using mobile, when I select Windows/Facebook, it redirects me to the login page. After providing my credentials, the service returns but the redirection of the url leads to page not found.

The url that is redirected seems like: http://mydomain.com/facebook.aspx?code=a_very_long_string

I get a message that page not found on the browser of the Android phone. The same code works fine when accessed through the browser of a desktop/laptop (Windows 7).

Please let me know if I am missing anything to make the service work for the mobile phone

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue. It turns out I cannot use server.Urlencode() .Net function before doing a custom redirection.

If I use it, the app breaks in the mobile platform. Removing it, fixed the issue and the url is successfully redirected.

I was doing a custom redirection after the authentication is successful and encoding the url. But seems that it breaks the application.

Not sure if it is a limitation in DotNetOpenAuth library or it is a limitation of the mobile browser.

Comment: What exactly were you sending to `Server.UrlEncode`?  DotNetOpenAuth encodes URLs automatically, so I wonder if you were double-encoding them?